# Remove empty/white space in plot when using win.metafile() in R

Tags: r, windows

How can I remove the empty space on the right side of my plot when using the following code? What might be the root cause for that? 
It seems to only happen if I use a secondary y-axis on the right side, which I need in this case.

```
library(zoo)
#--------------random data
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
z <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
z2 <- zoo(rnorm(5, sd = 0.2), x.Date)

#--------------create plot
win.metafile(filename = "Google.wmf", width = 7, height = 7)  

par(mar=c(5,4,4,4)) # custom margins
plot(z, type="l", xlab="Year", lt=1, lwd=1, ylab="Google Trend")
grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "lightgray", lty = "dotted",
     lwd = par("lwd"), equilogs = TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(z2, type="l", ann=FALSE, lt=1, lwd=3, yaxt="n")
axis(4, ylab="Test")  # Here?!
mtext("Index", side=4, line=2) # custom label on the right y-axis

legend("topright", c("z", "z2"), lty=c(1,1), 
       lwd=c(1,3),col=c("black","black"),
       box.col="black",bg="white")
title("Google")
dev.off()
```

If I adjust the width of my plot, the white space remains. I also tried changing the custom margins without success.

Second question (not so important): how to overwrite the gridlines with the z2 (done) and the z lines? In other words, how to bring the plotted lines to the "front"? Theoretically I would need to plot the gridlines first, but I cannot "put" them before the first plot of z.

EDIT/COMMENT: I have just found out that the problem does not happen if I use another PC... Here is the original image (if I compute the plot with my NB):

[image]

Comment: Note: This is only for Windows users.

Comment: @Pascal Is that a problem? And what if the problem also exists with other graphic file formats?

Comment: Simply, for example, Linux users cannot use `win.metafile` function, as it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Pascal Ok, added the windows tag. Thanks for this comment. I hope there are some windows users who use R here...

Comment: When I tried this using R version 3.2.0 Patched (2015-04-19 r68205) and Windows 8.1 there was no substantial whitespace.  Please post an image of what you are getting.

Comment: Well, that is odd. After your comment I computed the creation of the plot with another PC and there it works too...

Comment: Having the same issue, R 3.4.3 (on one computer, huge margins on left and bottom, twice the image size) and R 3.4 1 (different computer, margins not as large but almost half the image size). Both Window 10. Does not happen with .png and .jpg. Happens with ggsave and win.metafile with both base and ggplot plots.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to R nor to RStudio. I was having the same issue on two different laptops (both were plugged into large external monitors.... is yours?)

[Windows 7](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1030921) fix is here.

[Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025083/windows-scaling-issues-for-high-dpi-devices) fix is here. I used the "Workaround" section titled "Adjust display settings". Basically, set your display settings "scale and layout" to 100%.

Reboot to make display settings take effect for software.